# Hit an endpoint which there is data available to be processed in table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working in a standard spring-boot application (i.e a Microservice). there are several endpoints,services and repositories.

**Usecase**
I want to be able to parallel process several records as soon as they are available in a database table.
.There is an endpoint that I have created for this .

Currently I am calling this endpoint using a shell script (curl call ) through a cron job , but I a looking for am looking for an better alternative

**In a nutshell**

I have a query , whenever it returns some data , I want to process that data.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to parallel process several records as soon as they are available in a database table

Assuming you fetched the records and need to process them. The best way to do this would be using project reactor. Spring provides out of the box support for project reactor. An example:

```
Flux.<String>fromIterable(it) // lots of other types accepted as well
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.newParallel("async", 4)) // create 4 threads
    .doOnNext(str -> {
        // ... do something with data asynchronously
    })
    .subscribe();
```

I usually use mongodb and subscribe to "Change Stream" event which returns a `Flux<T>` that can be handled on the go.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [@EnableScheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) and [@EnableAsync](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html)